# Maven Surefire plugin "error in starting fork" while building project with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, surefire

I was trying building a Java plugin with Maven using Intellij IDEA until I came across an error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.803 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-16T16:34:55-10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project mc-hyperchat: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I realize that this is because of this line (that I found using the `-X` flag)

```
Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C ""D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\<username>\Documents\+GIT\mc-hyperchat\target\surefire\surefirebooter8505511050498586005.jar C:\Users\<username>\Documents\+GIT\mc-hyperchat\target\surefire\surefire5990474653240919844tmp C:\Users\<username>\Documents\+GIT\mc-hyperchat\target\surefire\surefire_08408900793313340679tmp"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I happen to come across somebody else with the exact same problem:

[Maven Surefire 2.13 fails to fork on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295183/maven-surefire-2-13-fails-to-fork-on-windows)

The accepted answer seems to be that his `JAVA_HOME` environment variable was invalid, so I checked mine:

[image]

I also echoed the variable on the Command Prompt to make sure it didn't have any quotation marks in it (also me running `cmd.exe` to see another `The system cannot find the path specified` message):

[image]

I'm convinced my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is correct. If that's the case, what else could've caused this problem?

Answer (score 17):

I found this to be a windows related error -

Open the Registry Editor
Navigate to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun and clear the values.
Also check HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun.

Comment: I lost all day because of this issue.Great  solution.Thanks

Comment: I cannot believe this worked. Suddenly remembered why I switched to gradle.

Comment: worked for me too, I had ansicon in that entry which I installed 6 months ago when reading and practising with the book "cucumber for java"

Comment: Hey @miconico, your solution also works for me. Could you please share us the way you troubleshoot the problem to know that issue is related to that AutoRun value in Registry ? Thanks

Comment: Another "worked for me". I had recently had a failed uninstall of Anaconda and my HKCU AutoRun had "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat".

Comment: same here, also had ansicon in value of AutoRun registry key